# I am required to demo and publicize my work, but I work on another manager's project

Tags: performance-reviews, manager

I have a situation in a team,where my manager is pushing all of us to 'record' more work in form code repository contributions , sending out mails to show off and do more demos.Each 3 months we have a evaluation,where he unfailingly puts me at average position in spite of working hard.The worst part of it is I work on product owned by a different manager.The aim of his actions seem only to seek his prominence in the organisation, that is in somewhat a dire condition.What should be my approach to tackle him or the situation.

Comment: Welcome to The Workplace.SE. I have edited the title of your question to be more descriptive of your situation. If it does not accurately describe your question, please feel free to edit it. As it was written, a generic plea for help is unlikely to generate a lot of interest in the list of new questions.

Comment: Just to clarify: are you saying that your manager is giving you lower evaluations because the work you are doing is for a different manager, and thus not doing anything to help your current manager's visibility?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possible scenarios going on here...

**Your manager's job is at risk and he is trying to save it by asking his team to outperform.**

If he is putting unreasonable expectations on everyone, then you only have to go along with it for a short time. He probably won't be there much longer. However, the requirements you have described in the question do not seem unreasonable.

**Your whole team is at risk**

Your manager might be trying to help you all save yourselves by being more visibly productive within the organization. If this is the case, you should feel some appreciation for his helping you possibly save your job by giving you specific things to do rather than just telling you to work harder.

**You, personally, individually, are at risk**

If these expectations are set for just you, then you should know that your job is the one being scrutinized. You need to meet them to save your job. If this is the case, then you should also appreciate that he has given you something clear and concrete to do to save yourself.

**Finally, this is simply how they have decided to measure performance of the software developers in the organization**

It's not uncommon to ask for code commits and demos. Quarterly performance reviews seems a little more often than is common, but it's not unreasonable. In our organization, we often measure task completion/progress (doc/code commits, etc.) on a weekly basis.

**What to do about it**

Regardless of the scenario, your expectations have been clearly set. If you don't meet them, it doesn't matter that you're working hard. You're underperforming.

Since you're working on another manager's project, you should inform him/her of the performance expectations placed on you and ask his/her approval to demo your contributions on his/her project to your manager.

To prove you're committing code, you can simply show your manager your commit logs and diffs (if necessary).

Everyone appreciates someone who works hard. But if your hard work doesn't accomplish what your manager has set as your priorities, it's as though you're climbing a ladder that's leaning against the wrong wall. You won't get to where you're supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

**"Consult the manager who owns the product you work..."**

Tell him about your problems and make sure you don't let your emotions show (don't put too many negatives about your manager).. One more thing you must be ready to prove the allegations you are making, i.e. to show that you are being unfairly targeted you need to show the records of your work and its quality.

If things don't improve even after that, than one of the following approach can be used..

**1. If you want to stay here,**
Try to find out the reason why this person is targeting you. Make friends who are in his good book. Increase your skills and somehow make him aware that you want to work directly under his hierarchy..Talk more to him about the things in which his response is expected. That may change his perception of you (which is a key here)..the list is endless...

**2. If you had enough and want to leave,**

Start looking for the suitable job. **Leave !!**.